# Conectar Python con la base de datos MySQL proporcionada por WAMP Server

Tags: mysql, python, wamp

En los últimos días he estado aprendiendo PHP y MySQL, y me he apoyado del paquete WAMP el cual viene con el servidor web Apache, el GBD MySQL y las librerías de PHP. He querido saber si es posible, teniendo instalado tanto el paquete WAMP como Python (obviamente ambos de manera independiente), realizar una conexión a la base de datos de MySQL proporcionada por WAMP mediante Python. De ser así esto, ¿Qué aspectos debería de configurar del paquete WAMP? ¿Es necesario que descargue algun API de Python?

Espero puedan resolverme esta duda.

Comment: revisa por favor el enlace en la zona de comentarios, parece ser esta pregunta ya se hizo y tiene respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pymysql
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                                user='usuario',
                                password='contraseña',
                                db='base_de_datos',
                                charset='utf8mb4',
                                cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor = connection.cursor()
sql = "SELECT * FROM tabla"
cursor.execute(sql)
result = cursor.fetchone()

connection.close()
```

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias! Funcionó perfectamente.